# In a PHP script that produces an image at random, why does calling it multiple times on a page always produce the same image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a web page April fools prank where all images on the page are replaced with an image picked at random from a selection of images. I have a php script that picks the image at random and sends the image:

```
<?
$files = array('pacman', 'blinky', 'cherry', 'clyde', 'inky', 'pinky'); 

$name = $files[array_rand($files)] . '.png';

header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($name));

readfile($name);
?>
```

This works fine, returning a random image each time it is visited.

Step 2 was replacing all image source attributes with the script, which I do by including a javascript file that has contents that looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').attr('src', 'april.php')
});
```

This also works, except for one catch: it seems to only pick a random image once. That is to say, all images on the page will be the same image. If I refresh, it will be a randomly selected image, but it will be the same image for everything on the page until the next refresh.

I would guess that the browsers are caching it the first time and are not actually calling the php script, but I'm not sure how to go about disabling, or working aorund it.

So, why does this happen, and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Have you tried implementing the randomisation feature within your JS? Not an answer but a workaround.

Comment: [Dilbert on random numbers](http://assets.amuniversal.com/321a39e06d6401301d80001dd8b71c47)

Comment: Try to add a cache buster random number to the img SRC attribute, like 
$('img').attr('src', 'april.php?'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));

This would tell you if it is a caching issue.

Comment: You have to [seed](http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) the random number generator before first `rand` call. Otherwise it will generate the same numbers sequence (as you get now).

Comment: Arrays are your friend. Ditch the switch. `$files = ['pacman', 'blinky', 'cherry', 'clyde', 'inky', 'pinky']; $name = $files[array_rand($files)] . '.png';`

Comment: @AlexHowansky in this case change .jpg to .png

Comment: @Xorifelse Ooops, you're right, thanks for noting. No need to remove.

Comment: You can also drop the `fopen()` and replace the `fpassthru()` with a `readfile($name)`

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have edited the php in accordance with your comments. I didn't know about `array_rand()` for some reason. I do now though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP will generate a random image every time, however your browser keeps that image in cache and loads that instead.

Add this to your PHP code:

```
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

However, in your case since the image is already loaded you must first hard-refresh the page <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

An alternative method is adding a get request to the URL.

```
  $('img').attr('src', 'april.php?t=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 60000) + 1);
```

For multiple images: (Credits to @Francesco de Guytenaere for spotting it)

```
  $('img').each(function(){ $(this).attr('src', 'april.php?t=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 60000) + 1); });
```

However this will change every image on the entire page, maybe you want to use a selector and only pick images that have a specific `data-tag` like so.

```
  <img src="image/to/background" />
  <img src="" data-cache="no" />
  <img src="" data-cache="no" />

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img[data-cache='no']").each(f.....
  });
```

Comment: This won't work; you should wrap it in an `each`; `$('img').each(function() { $(this).attr('src', 'april.php?t=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 60000) + 1); });`. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this code replace the URL of every image on the page to a random one? Might want to use a selector on that `[data-cache='no']` -> `<img data-cache="no" />`

Comment: Yes, if you read the question `This also works, except for one catch: it seems to only pick a random image once. That is to say, all images on the page will be the same image. If I refresh, it will be a randomly selected image, but it will be the same image for everything on the page until the next refresh.` that means it's not just a caching problem, but also a problem of setting al img src attributes to the same source; hence the loop. You should still add the cachebuster of course, that's why the answer is mostly ok. (Edited :) )

Comment: Good catch, did not expect multiple image tags.

Comment: @Ciccio You are correct. Your edit was very helpful.

Comment: @FrancescodeGuytenaere Updated your name in the answer.